# How do I provide daily report to my boss during remote working?

Tags: communication, management, covid-19, work-from-home

Our company asked us to work from home due to COVID things. I am an R&D, my work is mostly programming. My boss asked us to provide a daily update, What is the best way to give my boss a daily based update? 
What software would you recommend? I would like to be a bit creative and assure my boss that I am working well, so looking for your suggestion guys.

Our company uses Microsoft Team for meetings and communication.

Comment: This is not the time or situation to be creative. If there is an obvious way to do it, use that. If not, ask your boss. The boss will be able to work more efficiently if all subordinate reports come through the same channel.

Comment: Why creative, what's wrong with a paragraph long email?

Comment: When I asked he told a brief update that what we are doing. He did not tell any details.

Comment: OK, so give him a brief update on what you're doing. What's the difficulty?

Comment: Send him an email.  If you're like me, you'll be sorely tempted to include a graphic for Cohn's Law (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cohn's-Law-.png for a suitable example).

Comment: How did you share that information with your boss before working from home ? face to face ? email ? chat ?

Comment: Open Microsoft Outlook, type an update, press send.

Comment: There are a hundred ways to give your boss this update. The best one is the one they want you to use. Your boss is the best one to answer this question, not this forum.

Comment: Do you have access to some collaboration software? Something like SharePoint. That might let you build a quick tool for your team to all report in a consistent fashion in the same place that your boss can look at, in open cultures everyone might be able to see it. Offering to build this could be something your boss thanks you for if they like that kind of thing. Until you know exactly the requirements for such a tool use email. If your boss didn’t give another option they almost certainly assumed email went without saying, it’s the default business communication tool.

Answer (score 9):

You should ask your boss what the preferred format for your situation should be.

*Here's the format I asked everyone on my team to send me each week.*

**1) What I worked on this week:**

I'm just looking for bullet items here.  The basics of what you have done for the week. I don't need to know how many hours you spent on things, just what you were doing.

For example:

- Wrote Test Plan for new Zerble Suite 7.0 feature XXX
- Completed testing of Framis 3.2 SR6 using AB&T database
- Attended planning meeting for Zerble Suite 8.0
- etc, etc

**2) What I plan to work on next week:**

Again, just the basics.
I'm looking to see what is on your plate for the upcoming week.

**3) Unplanned Activities:**

This will help me better keep track of progress on our schedules versus all the other activities we participate in.

This should include:

- any work not normally part of your weekly routine
- any work on customer or hitlist problems
- any work helping out other teams
- basically anything not directly involved with QA, testing, creating test cases, etc for the upcoming scheduled release(s)

**4) Time away next week:**

Please tell me if you are expecting to be out of the office during the upcoming week.
I don't need to know too much detail here, just when you won't be here, and a general reason as to why.

For example:

- Vacation day Tuesday, February 10

**5) Issues and Concerns**

Anything I should know about.
If there's anything getting in the way of your work, here's where you can note it.

For example:

- Memory upgrade on Bigtest server has been delayed.  Without the additional memory, my load testing cannot be completed.

Comment: where they share this report? My boss asked for a daily update.

Comment: @nikki you “share” it by email or drop a text file into teams - having it carved into a stone slab and delivered is not very effective...

Comment: @nikki We use a simple shared OneNote table - shared via Teams. The little table has a row for each employee. Everyone adds his "last week" and "next week" bullet points. For every week we add a new table. Has to be filled out by friday, when we do our standup. For daily use just adjust accordingly...You should most certainly not spend hours to sum up what you did each day, else you'll have nothing to sum up.

Comment: @nikki But your takeaway from this answer should not be "do it like Joe did," it should be "ask your manager how he wants it, format and channel, and he should give you an answer like this."

Answer (score 1):

For a daily report, the format of the Daily Stand Up in Scrum works reasonably well

- What have you completed since the last meeting?
- What do you plan to complete by the next meeting?
- What is getting in your way?

It it takes you more than 10 minutes to prepare it feels excessive for a daily report.

If you want to get creative set up a shared document. Spreadsheet works well here (Excel or Google Sheets). One row per day (newest on top), one column per questions. Each day just add a row at the top and fill in the three questions. All information is in one spot and it's consistent from day to week to month. You can add columns for more higher level planning as needed.

See https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/three-qs/#q=~(infinite~false~filters~(postType~(~'page~'post~'aa_book~'aa_event_session~'aa_experience_report~'aa_glossary~'aa_research_paper~'aa_video)~tags~(~'three*20questions))~searchTerm~'~sort~false~sortDirection~'asc~page~1)